# Javascript img source error when html checked

Tags: javascript, html

I have code for changing a banner based on a date (ie Thanksgiving, etc).  The code works fine, but when I run a html checker on it (validator.w3.org) it comes up showing an error:

> Error: Bad value  for attribute src on element img: Must be non-empty.

Is there a way to do it, where it won't cause an error?

```
<body>
  <img id="Logo" src="" alt="Correct Image">
  <script>
    // Just determine the appropriate source:
    var d = new Date();
    var Today = d.getDate();
    var Month = d.getMonth();
    var src;
    if (Month === 4 && (Today >= 21 && Today <= 23)) {
      src = "/images/holiday.png";
    } else {
      src = "/images/default.png";
    } 

    // And then set the image to it:
    document.getElementById("Logo").src = src;
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: You could just set it to the "default" image. But, as you know, it's irrelevant anyway because your script will always set it to one image or the other. (I guess the argument is that users with JS turned off should see something - but who actually does that these days?)

Comment: The error seems pretty self-explanatory.  The `src` attribute on an `img` element must be non-empty.  Yours is empty.

Comment: You could also include more than one image, each with its `src` set up correctly, but initially hide all of them. Then turn the correct one visible based on the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
 <body>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <script>
      var d = new Date();
      var Today = d.getDate();
      var Month = d.getMonth();
      var src;
      if (Month === 4 && (Today >= 21 && Today <= 23)) {
        src = "/images/holiday.png";
      } else {
       src = "/images/default.png";
      }
      let img = `<img src=${src} alt="Correct Image">`;
      document.getElementById('logo').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', img);
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: try to create your img in DOM because the src shouldn't be empty, hope this helpfull

Answer (score 1):

The validator is exactly what you think it is - a validator. It checks the bare HTML you give to it for errors. An image without a source is, in pure HTML, absolutely useless, and so the validator raises an error since `src` needs a value.

If you are setting the image source via JavaScript, then there is no issue with the functionality - it's just a matter of whether or not you want the validator to approve of your HTML.

You can think of it as being similar to a compiler warning - sometimes it's informing you of something that has gone horribly wrong, and sometimes it's informing you that something isn't absolutely correct but likely won't break any functionality. This case with the validator is similar to the latter case.

As a general note, most browsers are very lenient with this kind of thing. The w3 validator isn't a browser and does not have context as to anything besides that which you have provided it with.

tl;dr don't worry too much about it, and add a default value if you want to silence the warning. Since you're going to be setting the contents of the img source in your JavaScript, you can put pretty much anything inside - e.g. `<img id="Logo" src="anything_can_go_here_since_it_will_be_replaced.jpg" alt="Correct Image">`.

Note that if someone has disabled JavaScript in their browser, your code won't set the correct image source, but at the same time most of the internet won't function for them, so that shouldn't be too much of a concern.

Comment: This is a good answer in theory, but not to this question, which is `Is there a way to do it, where it won't cause an error?`